# When using conventional means to control a heating element, how does it affect the peak required VA?

Tags: pwm, temperature, inverter

This question is similar to two others, [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/171135/controlling-an-electric-water-heater) and [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/141212/how-to-control-power-to-a-water-heater), but with a small difference.

To allow a bit of context: Suppose I have a winters day with lots of sunshine. I have an off-grid PV system, and the PV modules are making more power than can be used at the moment. My inverter is however limited to 1600VA, which limits what appliances I can use to dump this excess.

I also have a 3kw hot water cylinder, which presently runs from grid power. It has a standing loss of at least 2kwh a day, and there is a good 5kwh space between 55 and 85 centigrade (assuming 150 liters of water). It would make a good candidate for dumping excess, especially in winter when more hot water is used.

I can obviously not do this at full power due to the small inverter. In theory, however, the heating element has a power factor of 1 (or very very close), and if I drive it at half the voltage/current it would just take 4 times longer to get the same heat in there, but it should still work.

Traditionally you would do this with something that resembles a dimmer switch, some kind of PWM control, or you'd just rely on the thermal mass of the water and turn it full-on/full-off, but that can't be done here due to small inverter.

My question here: How does it affect overall required VA (because inverters are rated in VA, not watts) if you use something akin to a dimmer switch or PWM control? The overall average consumption may be below the inverter rating, but if it does so by creating extremely high current spikes at low duty cycles, I cannot imagine the inverter would like that very much.

I suppose you can shorten this question to: Can you use a dimmer switch (of sufficient capacity) to drive a large heating element from a small inverter. I have a feeling the answer is no. What are the alternatives?

Comment: Do you have to power the heating element from the inverter? Maybe you can connect your heating element directly from the source.

Comment: Agreed. The inverter will have losses and probably won't like the dimmer switch. DC heating will be most efficient. Your problem will be finding a suitable means of attaching a heater to your hot water cylinder.

Comment: Good point. I know there are people selling DC elements. Something to investigate. Thanks.

Comment: Many water heaters actually have three heating elements. In single phase operation they are connected in parallel, while in three phase operation they are connected in a [star AKA Y connection](http://m.imgur.com/D6dW76v). If your water heater fits this category, you could just switch the three elements individually (each element = 1 kW) to vary the power.

Comment: In your country that may be common :-) In South Africa, they are mostly single phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a transformer or a Variac to reduce the voltage without affecting the power factor much. It should be easy to find a 2:1 transformer. Be sure to prevent the transformer from back feeding if full power is applied, or you will have a bad day.

Comment: Indeed. This is a rather obvious answer, come to think of it, and I'm ashamed to admit I didn't think of it. The simplest solutions and all. Finding a 2:1 transformer will be easy. We're a 230V country, so existing adaptations for American equipment will do the trick.